# Iptables: Multiple -d flags not allowed(-dport and -d)

Tags: iptables

I tried to add a command like this in my iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -d 2.25.52.5 -dport 6784 -j DROP
```

And I got

```
iptables v1.4.21: multiple -d flags not allowed
```

I'm trying to drop RSTs sent from my machine to 2.25.52.5:6784.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-d is destination address, if you want destination port please use --dport 6784

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I used **-dport** instead of **--dport** and was unable to notice the difference looking into manuals.